# Setting name of DOM-created element fails in IE -- workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer

I got bit hard by this today:

```
function mk_input( name, val ) {
    var inp = document.createElement( 'input' );
    inp.name = name;
    inp.value = val;
    inp.type = 'hidden';

    return inp;
}
```

As it turns out, setting the `name` of an element created via `createElement` doesn't work in IE. It doesn't cause an error or anything, it just silently fails, causing one to ponder why their hidden fields aren't getting populated correctly.

As far as I can tell, there's no workaround. You have to just bite the bullet and create the `<input>` tag through string manipulation and stick it in with `.innerHTML` instead.

Is there a better way? Perhaps with something like jQuery? I did a cursory search and didn't find anything exactly akin to `createElement` in JQuery, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Does it work if you set the name once the node is in the DOM ?

Comment: @Fabien, no, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to re-iterate the problem: in IE, programatically setting the `name` attribute on an element created via `document.createElement('input')` is not reflected in `getElementsByName`, `form.elements` (if appending to a form), and is not submitted with the `form` (again, if appending to a form) [[Reference](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/10/bug-235-createelement-is-broken-in-ie.html)].

Here's the workaround I've used in the past (adapted to your question [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(VS.85,loband).aspx)):

```
function mk_input( name, val ) {
    var inp;
    try {
        inp = document.createElement('<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" />');
    } catch(e) {
        inp = document.createElement("input");
        inp.type = "hidden";
        inp.name = name;
    }
    inp.value = val;
    return inp
}
```

This is akin to feature detection (as opposed to browser detection). The first `createElement` will succeed in IE, while the latter will succeed in standards-compliant browsers.

And of course the jQuery equivalent since you tagged the question as such:

```
function mk_input( name, val ) {
    return $('<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" />')
        .val(val)
        .get(0)
}
```

(as a sidenote, under the hood jQuery is doing what you describe in your question: it creates a dummy `<div>` and sets its `innerHTML` to the `<input type="...` string passed above).

As @jeffamaphone points out, this bug has been fixed in IE8.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. I really hate mixing in HTML string manipulations within Javascript, but it looks like I don't have a choice here. :(

Answer (score 2):

They fixed this in IE8.  In previous versions, you need to include the name when you call createElement.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703821(VS.85).aspx):

> Internet Explorer 8 and later can set
>   the NAME attribute at run time on
>   elements dynamically created with the
>   IHTMLDocument2::createElement method.
>   To create an element with a NAME
>   attribute in earlier versions of
>   Internet Explorer, include the
>   attribute and its value when using the
>   IHTMLDocument2::createElement method.

Here is the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536389(VS.85).aspx):

```
var newRadioButton = document.createElement("<INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='RADIOTEST' VALUE='First Choice'>")
```