# Dynamically added JavaScript not finding dynamically added fields in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, yui, yui-autocomplete

I have a table which has a button to "Add Rows". This button adds a row dynamically with JQuery. It works by copying the first ... and then replacing all the id=".." with an incremented number.

The problem is that the rows have a YUI AutoComplete which looks like the following:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="location_num[0]" value="508318" maxLength="25" style="width:230px" id="location_num[0]"/>
    <input type="textbox" name="location_numDisplayDesc[0]" value="WINNIPEG" maxLength="25" style="width:230px" id="location_numDisplayDesc[0]"/>
    <div id="Container_location_num[0]" style="display:inline;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Initialize autocomplete
        var location_numAC = new YAHOO.widget.AutoComplete(
            "location_numDisplayDesc[0]",
            "Container_location_num[0]",
            locationDataSource,
            acConfig);

        location_numAC.useShadow = true
        location_numAC.useIFrame = true
        location_numAC.dataErrorEvent.subscribe(acErrorFunction);

        // Format results to include the reference number
        location_numAC.formatResult = function(resultItem, query) {
            return resultItem[0];
        };

        // Clear key before request
        location_numAC.dataRequestEvent.subscribe(function fnCallback(e, args) {
        YAHOO.util.Dom.get("location_num[0]").value = ""; });

        // Set key on item select
        location_numAC.itemSelectEvent.subscribe(function(event, args) {
            YAHOO.util.Dom.get("location_num[0]").value = args[2][1];
        });

        // Clear key when description is cleared
        location_numAC.textboxBlurEvent.subscribe(function fnCallback(e, args) {
            if (isEmpty(YAHOO.util.Dom.get("location_numDisplayDesc[0]").value)) {
                YAHOO.util.Dom.get("location_num[0]").value = "";
            } // end if
        });
    </script>
</td>
```

This code works fine in Firefox and the newly created AutoCompletes work, but in IE (6 & 7) I am getting an error that means that the location_num_AC is not being created successfully. I believe that it's because that it's not reading the newly created inputs or div as it should. I've tried wrapping the javascript with

```
$("Container_location_num[0]").ready(function {...});
```

but that didn't seem to work. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form fields that are inserted into the DOM in IE don't add to the forms collection as you might expect.

Normally you can refer to a form field one of two ways:

```
document.forms[0]["myFormName"];
document.forms[0][12];
```

That is, by its form field name or by its index. But when you *add* a form field to the DOM in IE you **can't** refer to it by name, only by its index. If your code (or any supporting code) is looking for a form field in the collection by its name you've obviously got a problem.

If your only key is the name you can loop through all the form fields by index and find what you're looking for, but that's obviously going to be a linear operation. You can also loop through and find which form fields are indexed numerically but not by name and update the form object yourself.

I don't have enough detail to know how (or if) this is occurring in your project, but it's one of those IE quirks that sounds like it might be playing a role since you're adding fields dynamically.

Comment: Explanation/workaround for IE is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650797/setting-name-of-dom-created-element-fails-in-ie-workaround/1651304#1651304 (FYI you can refer to dynamic elements by name just fine in IE, however the devil's in the details)