# Increment a number in a string in with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I get the name of an input element, which is a string with a number (**`url1`**). I want to increment the number by 1 (**`url2`**) in the easiest and quickest way possible.

My way would be to get `\d` / restofstring, `++` the match, then put together number with restofstring. Is there a better way?

Update:

My final (dummy)code became:

```
var liNew = document.createElement('li'); 
liNew.innerHTML = liOld.innerHTML; 
var els = Y.Dom.getChildrenBy(liNew, function(el) { 
    return el.name.match(/\d+$/); 
} // YUI method where the function is a test 
for (var i = 0, el; el = els[i]; i++) { 
    el.name = el.name.replace(/\d+$/, function(n) { return ++n }); 
} 
list.appendChild(liNew);
```

Comment: Er, you can't just change form element names like that in IE. You're gonna run into issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650797/setting-name-of-dom-created-element-fails-in-ie-workaround

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. If I end up needing to support IE for this, I'll use YUI Element instead.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about:

```
'url1'.replace(/\d+$/, function(n){ return ++n }); // "url2"
'url54'.replace(/\d+$/, function(n){ return ++n }); // "url55"
```

There we search for a number at the end of the string, cast it to `Number`, increment it by 1, and place it back in the string. I think that's the same algo you worded in your question even.

Reference:

- [`String.prototype.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) - can take a regex

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the solution I made with your example

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.

Comment: Here is a slightly modified version that works for all the numbers in a string: `"url5part6".replace(/\d+/g, function(n){ return ++n }); //returns "url6part7"`

Comment: Good answer but I fail to see the part where we "cast it to Number"

Comment: `++` did that. It converts the operand to number implicitly and then increase that by one before returning the final value.

Answer (score 7):

Simple. Use a substitution function with regular expressions:

```
s = 'abc99abc';
s = s.replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; });
```

will set variable *s* to: `abc100abc`

But it gets more complicated if you want to make sure you only change a certain parameter in the URL:

```
s = '?foo=10&bar=99';
s = s.replace(/[&?]bar=\d+/, function(attr) {
  return attr.replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; });
});
```

will set variable *s* to: `?foo=10&bar=100`

Comment: Hm, the question was not about get parameters?

Comment: If you read the question carefully, the asker did not specify what exactly he wanted to change; not even that the number would be *at the end* of the URL -- he just used it in his example. I figured changing GET parameters would be a likely use case.

Comment: "the name of an input element" = `<input name="url1">`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and pass it a function to use to replace the matched section:

```
str.replace(/\d+/, function(number) { return parseInt(number, 10) + 1; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK. You might want to use a regex like `^(.*?)(\d+)$`, making sure the number you're grabbing is at the end of the string.