# Incrementing an integer at the end of a string in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string in the following format:

```
\main\stream\foo.h\3
```

it may have more or less "sections", but will always end with a slash followed by an integer. Other examples include:

```
\main\stream2309\stream222\foo.c\45

\main\foo.c\9
```

I need to, in Perl, increment the number at the end of the string and leave the rest alone.  I found an example on this site that does exactly what I want to do (see [Increment a number in a string in with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742798/increment-a-number-in-a-string-in-with-regex)) only the language is Javascript. The solution given was:

```
.replace(/\d+$/,function(n) { return ++n })
```

I need to do the same thing in Perl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `/e` regex modifier to put executable code in your replacement string.

Something like:

```
$string =~ s/(\d+)$/$1 + 1/e;
```

should work.

Comment: Too bad auto-increment is limited to strings that match `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`

Answer (score 2):

Try `$var =~ s/(\d+$)/($1 + 1)/e`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an underscored suffix and the original string might not have a suffix:

```
value
value_1
value_2
...
```

you can use this:

```
$foo =~ s{_?(\d*)$}{'_'.($1 eq '' ? 1 : $1+1)}e
```