# How to increment number in string using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript

The id of my textarea is string  and of this format

> id='fisher[27].man'

I would like to clone the textarea and increment the number and get the id as `fisher[28].man` and prepend this to the existing textarea.

Is there a way to get this done easily with jquery?

```
var existingId = $("#at textarea:last").attr('id');
var newCloned = lastTextArea.clone();
var newId = newCloned.attr('id');
//add the index number after spliting
//prepend the new one to 
newCloned.prepend("<tr><td>" + newCloned + "</td></tr>");
```

There has to be easier way to clone, get index number, split and prepend.

I'm  have also tried to do this with regEx

```
var existingIdNumber = parseInt(/fisher[(\d+)]/.exec(s)[1], 10);
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Correct regex would be this

```
/fisher\[\d+\].man/
```

Here is a way through through which you would extract the the id.

```
id = text.replace(/fisher\[(\d+)\].man+/g,"$1");
//Now do whatever you want with the id
```

Similarly, Same replacement technique can be used to get an incremented id as:

```
existingId = 'fisher[27].man';
newId = existingId .replace(/(\d+)+/g, function(match, number) {
       return parseInt(number)+1;
});
console.log(newId);
```

#### [Demo with both usage](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/stXVu/2/)

Comment: @vol7ron, Thanks you for the suggestion, hope you will like the edit.

Comment: awesome, removed my comment :)

Comment: @Starx, thank you for you great answer and my question is if it is possible to increment number except number with special character e.g. existingId = 'fisher[27][ $27].man'; I would like increment [27] only, not [$27]. Regards Jan

Comment: @JanZitniak One way is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/stXVu/134/)

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/D3yvL/)

No need for all the extra code.  Change this line:

```
var newId = newCloned.attr('id');
```

To:

```
var newId  = newCloned.attr('id').replace( /(\d+)/, function(){return arguments[1]*1+1} );
```

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution from [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742798/increment-a-number-in-a-string-in-with-regex):

```
'url1'.replace(/\d+$/, function(n){ return ++n }); // "url2"
'url54'.replace(/\d+$/, function(n){ return ++n }); // "url55"
```

Very clean and readable.

Comment: To fully solve request from original post, need to remove $ from regular expression so the number doesn't need to be at the end of string.

Answer (score 2):

I am amazed that there is not any good implementation for this simple thing. All of the examples forget the case of having zeroes before the number. The code below should take care of that.

```
// 'item001' => 'item002'
function increment_alphanumeric_str(str){
    var numeric = str.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    var prefix = str.split(numeric)[0];

    function increment_string_num(str){
        var inc = String(parseInt(str)+1);
        return str.slice(0, str.length-inc.length)+inc;
    }

    return prefix+increment_string_num(numeric);
}
```

Example:

```
> increment_alphanumeric_str('test09')
'test10'
```

Only drawback is that this will break if we have something like `'test99'`.

Comment: it will not works if the string having alphabetic case in the suffix  is Like This A001B

Comment: This does not work if you go from 99 to 100, it will output 9100.

Answer (score 1):

If your Id has this format

```
id='fisher[27].man'
```

You can do something like this

```
   var startIndex = newId.indexOf('[');
   var endIndex = newId.indexOf(']');
   var number = parseInt(newId.substr(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1));
   var incrementedId = number + 1;  // 28
```

where

```
var newId = newCloned.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a regex replacement:

```
var id = "fisher[27].man";
id = id.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(match, number) {
    return '[' + (parseInt(number, 10) + 1) + ']';
});
// id is now "fisher[28].man"
```

Comment: What if you have `fisher[07].man`? It gives back `fisher[8].man`

Comment: a) Zero-padding didn't seem to be an element of the OP's use case. b) If you think this is a concern in my implementation, check out the accepted answer by @Starx, which omits the radix argument from `parseInt` and therefore [risks parsing in base 8 for 0-padded numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).