# Splitting up input using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java

I am making a program that lets a user input a chemical for example C9H11N02. When they enter that I want to split it up into pieces so I can have it like C9, H11, N, 02. When I have it like this I want to make changes to it so I can make it C10H12N203 and then put it back together. This is what I have done so far. using the regular expression I have used I can extract the integer value, but how would I go about get C10, H11 etc..?

```
System.out.println("Enter Data");

Scanner k = new Scanner( System.in );
String input = k.nextLine();

String reg = "\\s\\s\\s";
String [] data;

data = input.split( reg );

int m = Integer.parseInt( data[0] );
int n = Integer.parseInt( data[1] );
```

Comment: @BheshGurung don't be so sure...

Comment: i dont understand, what string are you trying to spilt with a space as delimiter ??

Comment: You can do this in JavaScript by calling a function from the regex - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742798/increment-a-number-in-a-string-in-with-regex - but this is Java...

Comment: @BheshGurung See? You were wrong. It's *easily* done with regex

Comment: @BheshGurung See my answer for the solution and some test code that demonstrates splitting correctly even with multi-letter chemical symbols like `Br` and with multi-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code should allow you to extract the various elements and their associated count. Of course, brackets make things more complicated, but you didn't ask about them!

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]*)([0-9]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String element = matcher.group(1);
    int count = 1;
    if (matcher.groupCount > 1) {
        try {
            count = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Regex means we should never get here!
        }
    }
    // Do stuff with this component
}
```

Comment: That pattern will get the wrong result for CH4, for example - it should return [C, H4] but I think it will return [CH4]. Two-letter chemical symbols are always uppercase-lowercase.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html):

```
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])");
```

Look arounds are zero-width, non-consuming assertions.

This regex splits the input where the two look arounds match:

- `(?<=.)` means "there *is* a preceding character" (ie not at the start of input)
- `(?=[A-Z])` means "the next character is a capital letter" (All elements start with `A-Z`)

Here's a test, including a double-character symbol for some edge cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "C9KrBr2H11NO2";
    String[] parts = input.split("(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Output:

```
[C9, Kr, Br2, H11, N, O2]
```

---

If you then wanted to split up the individual components, use a nested call to `split()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "C9KrBr2H11NO2";
    for (String component : input.split("(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])")) {
        // split on non-digit/digit boundary
        String[] symbolAndNumber = component.split("(?<!\\d)(?=\\d)");
        String element = symbolAndNumber[0];
        // elements without numbers won't be split
        String count = symbolAndNumber.length == 1 ? "1" : symbolAndNumber[1];
        System.out.println(element + " x " + count);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C x 9
Kr x 1
Br x 2
H x 11
N x 1
O x 2
```

Comment: I deleted my comments. +1 for the proof that my comment was wrong. It's a good solution.

Comment: Possibly cleaner than my solution, but I'd be interested to see if there's any difference performance-wise... Also you might want to use a `Pattern` so you don't have to recompile the regex every time.

Answer (score 2):

Did you accidentally put zeroes into some of those formula where the letter "O" (oxygen) was supposed to be? If so:

```
"C10H12N2O3".split("(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])");

[C10, H12, N2, O3]

"CH2BrCl".split("(?<=[0-9A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])");

[C, H2, Br, Cl]
```

Comment: sorry, I think i did. Once it is extracted like this could I break in down either further so I could add 1 to C10 to make it C11?

Comment: +1 for the lookBehind - but this doesn't work for some combinations of two-letter chemical symbols e.g. CH2BrCl

Comment: @DNA: I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: Nice. I think you can simplify to just `(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])` ?

Comment: @Joe24: In that case, you may want to go with jrtc27's answer. This solution would require a subsequent regular expression to pull the number out of the token.